# "Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method" from CglibAopProxy$ProxyCallbackFilter when used @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactions

I am trying to use @Transactional and have only one component scan in whole application to scan all packages and classes.

```
@Transactional(isolation= Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
<context:component-scan base-package="parent app package"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

While spring tries to load and create proxy for beans to apply Transactional advice, I see couple of logs as below,

```
DEBUG CglibAopProxy$ProxyCallbackFilter  -                 - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public
```

To validate if transaction working or not, I am invoking isolation level as below and seems to be not working.

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel()
```

Anyone had this issue or any work around to resolve the issue. Please help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check the logs if you see other types of DEBUG messages, like starting a transaction, committing etc. Can you provide a complete log file (via pastebin.com) of your app running a Transactional method?